# Creating arbitrary size array/images in opencv?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, matrix, porting

Below is a line I have implemented in MATLAB, which indicates the rows and columns of the matrix is flexible. I can add any number of objects having dimension 3. I need to do the same in OpenCV.

```
ColorValues(:,:,3)=0;
```

---

Below is the code I want to convert to OpenCV:

```
ColorValues(:,:,3)=0;
for i=1:M
    for j=1:N
        if (bw(i,j)==0)
            ColorValues(i,j,:)=image(i,j,:);
        else
            ColorValues(i,j,:)=0;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: in MATLAB, are you trying to create a new matrix, or are trying to simply assign zeros to the third slice along the third dimension? That line as is is read as zeroing out the B channel in an RGB image

Comment: i have did this in matlab..i have created a matrix of  three dimension with flexible size .I want to do the same in opencv. The line i have written is in matlab.

Comment: my question still stands, what exactly do you want to achieve here? can you show a bit more of your MATLAB code..

Comment: below i have pasted my code need to convert to opencv..u can understand my goal here

Comment: ColorValues(:,:,3)=0;

for i=1:M
    for j=1:N
        
            if (bw(i,j)==0) 
                 ColorValues(i,j,:)=image(i,j,:);
            else
                 ColorValues(i,j,:)=0;
            end

    end
end

Comment: that is a very inefficient way of doing it. I assume you have a binary mask `bw` and you want to apply it to the image `image`? If so you can just use element-wise multiplication: `ColorValues = bsxfun(@times, img, bw);` in MATLAB. You can easily do an equivalent thing in OpenCV

Comment: yahh..if binary mask is zero then i will retrieve the value of rgb 'image' to ColorValues otherwise i will set it to zero. I did not understand your code. Can you please explain it little further. Also i  think element wise multiplication wont work ,since i need original value when bw=0 not bw=1,so i cant do that.

Comment: multiplication would work, i just forget to complement the mask (invert zeros/ones). The MATLAB code with `bsxfun` is simply multiplying each color channel by the mask, equivalent to: `img(:,:,i) .* mask` for each `i`. Anyway I posted an alternate OpenCV solution below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example in OpenCV. We use a mask of the same size as the input image to "zero" values in the image by using the [Mat::setTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-setto) method.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main()
{
    // read an RGB image
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (!img.data) {
        return -1;
    }

    // create a circular mask
    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);
    cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(img.rows/2,img.cols/2), 150, cv::Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

    // mask out the "on" values by setting them to zero
    img.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0), mask);

    // show result
    cv::namedWindow("demo", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("demo", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think what you want to achieve here is possible with opencv. Look at the [matrix constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat). You don't need to allocate the memory -or release it as soon as you do not need it; if you use the default constructor:

```
Mat A;
```

This will create a "flexible" matrix. If you want the type defined (as 3 channels); then you need to define the size, too. There is no constructor for that purpose.

One solution can be creating a non-flexible data as:

```
Mat B(1,3,CV_8UC1);
```

then use color data from this matrix.

As an another approach, you may want to take a look at standart library of C++; the `list` and `vector` structures may help you.

```
vector<vector<int> > imageCoordinates;
vector<int> RGB(3);
```

will create the flexible image plane; and fixed 3-channel in seperate datas.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i do it in C instead of c++.